# Reconnect to Process Started Via COM

Tags: c++, c, windows, com, ole

First, I'd like to note that I need to use the COM/OLE2 APIs, the low level stuff, the stuff you can put in a C Windows Console program. I can't use MFC. I can't use .NET.

My question is:

Given the following code:

```
CLSID clsid;    
HRESULT hr;

hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"InternetExplorer.Application", &clsid);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid,
                      NULL,
                      CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                      IID_IDispatch,
                      (void **)&(iePtr_));
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
```

Is there a way to write some information to the disk so that I can reconnect to the same instance of IE later on? Basically can "iePtr_" be stringified for later reconstitution by some other process?

Thanks.

---- added later------

The broader problem I am trying to solve is that I want to start an AutoCAD application, load some data into it, and then leave it running for my client to interact with. Later he will go back to my application and I want to reconnect to the same AutoCAD session and feed it more data.

Now, I full well realize I can keep the IDispatch pointer in memory in my application and I'll be able to continue to interact with the same AutoCAD process. That's my fallback position.

However, I use a "wrapper" program to do my COM stuff. So the wrapper is transient. My main application starts the wrapper, then the wrapper communicates, and then exits. I just want subsequent wrapper processes to be able to reconnect to the same AutoCAD process.

Why use a wrapper? Here's the working reason: My main application is a 32-bit application, but I can use a 64-bit wrapper and communicate with 64-bit AutoCAD. I need to be able to communicate with 64-bit AutoCAD and can probably not port my main application easily (500K+ lines of C++) vs. my wrapper program (couple hundred lines).

Comment: What's the broader problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You should use SUCCEEDED() instead of !FAILED() - that's what it is intended for. I'll edit the code.

Comment: Added "broader" picture stuff to the main post.

Comment: That sounds strange. The Autocad COM server is started as an out-proc (exe), isn't it. If so you don't care if it's 32- or 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application registered itself in the Running Object Table, you can use the [GetActiveObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221467.aspx) function to get a reference to the application object.

```
IUnknown *pUnknown;

hr = GetActiveObject(clsid, NULL, &pUnknown);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

hr = pUnknown->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void **)&(iePtr_));
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
```

Answer (score 0):

[CoMarshalInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678428(VS.85).aspx) (and related APIs) can be used to marshal an interface into another thread, process or different PC on the network. I don't know how long you are allowed to wait before completing the marshaling process, but in principal, if the object you are marshaling an interface to has not been closed the marshaling process can be completed later.

Being able to destroy an OLE object and later restore "the same object" is tied into what are called Monikers, and if you (can) understand those then your OLE/COM Juju is powerful indeed.

Comment: Allegedly, DCOM has a "garbage collection" mechanism that kills the stub for an object after 4 minutes, so that's a timeout to be aware of. Provided the object is hosted in its own process, you _should_ be able to marshal the interface ptr to a stream, write that to disk, and then reconstitute in another process, if only you do it within those 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making the wrapper layer long lived rather than transient, therefore it can easily hold a single reference to the third application.

The wrapper can still appear transient to the client code.
If you make the wrapper a COM singleton then each time you cocreate it, you will get back the same instance.

To ensure the wrapper lives for the lifetime of your client hold a reference from startup to shutdown.  This reference does not need to be wired through to other code.  All other code simply creates the singleton every time it wants it.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, that's impossible. The whole idea of COM is that the COM server is started transparently and only preserves state until you have stopped using its objects. After you've released the COM objects the COM subsystem is free to completely stop the server and there's no way to recreate the same process. The only way a similar result would be possible is to have a COM object with serialization methods that would permit saving the state into a stream and restoring it from a stream. But even then you would have to CoCreateInstance() again, obtain a new COM object interface pointer and call the restore method of that object.

The pointer you get from CoCreateInstance is only valid for the current process, if you save it on disk and restore later it will become invalid.

Comment: This seems a rather naive/purest view of COM - maybe the world would be a better place if real COM code only behaved that way.

Comment: @morechilli: That's the behavior implied by the model. Of course the implementation does what it does.